# Passing Array or Objects to function convert it to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my requirement, I have an array having datewise data like

```
$.each(dateWiseArr, function(index, currentDate){
    myDateArray[currentDate] = "myData";
    dateWiseOtherId[currentDate] = "otherId";
});
alert(myDateArray+"::"+dateWiseOtherId);//working fine and showing right data
$("#myBtn").attr("onClick", "myPassingFunction("+myDateArray+", "+dateWiseOtherId+")");

function myPassingFunction(myDateArray, dateWiseOtherId){
    alert(myDateArray[0]);//throw undefined
}
```

Now when I am press my button function call successfully but variables becomes string.

Let me know if you need more understanding.

Note: myDate

Comment: You're using an odd way of binding a `click` event. Look into a basic jQuery event tutorial - that will also solve your string issue.

Comment: that is not how you suppose to register listener in jQuery. Please have a look at http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I cannot bind click event onload as parameters and function are change as per condition

Comment: you might also want to use console.log (not in IE!) instead of nasty alert boxes

Comment: the reason this is not working for you is becouse you really are passing only the string representation of the array when you concat the onclick value like this.

Comment: @AMember I tried by using "click" function also, but all same

Comment: @geedubb thanks for suggestion, I will try next time, but currently stuck with this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a function instead of binding a string, then you don't need to convert the values to strings:

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
  myPassingFunction(myDateArray, dateWiseOtherId);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below. It should work.

```
$.each(dateWiseArr, function(index, currentDate){
    myDateArray[currentDate] = "myData";
    dateWiseOtherId[currentDate] = "otherId";
});

alert(myDateArray+"::"+dateWiseOtherId);//working fine and showing right data

$("#myBtn").click(function (event) {
     myPassingFunction(myDateArray, dateWiseOtherId);
});

function myPassingFunction(myDateArray, dateWiseOtherId){
    alert(myDateArray[0]);//throw undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right way of binding events: Check this working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vC4Yk/

```
var myDateArray = ["some data"];
var dateWiseOtherId = ["some other data"];

alert(myDateArray+"::"+dateWiseOtherId);//working fine and showing right data

$("#myBtn").click(function(){
   myPassingFunction(myDateArray, dateWiseOtherId);      
});

function myPassingFunction(myDateArray, dateWiseOtherId){
    alert(myDateArray[0]);
}   ​
```